# Remove date from Joomla template (YooTheme)

Tags: javascript, css, templates, joomla

I want to remove the date that's in left corner of this site http://www.gomainca.com/joomla30/index.php but I don't know where is it generated, I'm using a free YooTheme Joomla template.

The date has a "uk-float-left" class, I've tried this

```
.uk-float-left {
   display:none;
}
```

But, obviously, didn't work.

Can anybody help me? May be remove with JS? I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work. Have you checked the files or system cache if there is any?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can turn off the date through the template options in the backend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the ones that answered me!

I solved it with Javascript. the script lookout for the combination of classes (**uk-float-left uk-hidden-small uk-margin-small-top uk-margin-large-right**) and set the visibility to hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-float-left uk-hidden-small uk-margin-small-top uk-margin-large-right");
    var i;
        for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
</script>
```